# How to insert multiple variables from keyboard

Tags: bash, shell

I want to insert multiple names from keyboard like format:

```
A
B
C
```

I tried to use `while` loop like this:

```
name=$*
while [ "$name" != "done" ]
do
echo "name:"
read $name
echo "$name"
done
```

when i insert `"done"`, it will finish the loop and write all names to text file

Comment: Your script will not write all names to a text file. This is your question? How to write them to a text file?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Dear @Florin Ghita

please don't care about my script, it doesn't work. I mean i want to insert some names from keyboard and can write all that names to file or print out ...

Comment: what is wrong with `cat - > file`and `<Ctrl-D>` when done

Comment: @andlrc: not anything wrong, i just want to write a program can read data input from keyboard :D ...

Comment: @viet Isn't that what `cat -` does? ;)

Comment: @andlrc :D ... I understand ... haha ... thanks for your hint ...
okay ... "cat -" is enough ...

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with using `cat` and read from stdin?

```
cat -
```

You can redirect the output to a file and close the input file with `<Ctrl-D>`

```
$ cat - > new_file
hello
world
<Ctrl-D>
$ cat new_file
hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
read -p "Enter line : " line
if [[ $line = "done" ]]
then
  exit -1
  #-1 to show abnormal input ie "done"
else
  echo "$line" >> file #appending what you entered using >>
fi
done
```

Or idiomatically :

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/null > file #Emptying file if already exist
while read -p "Enter line : " line && [[ $line != "done" ]]
do
  echo "$line" >> file
done
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.sjssam

It worked ... you help me so much :D